# Azure Devtest Lab : Managing PAT for artifact repository

Tags: azure-devtest-labs

I am using PAT(Personal access token) in key vault as a secret and Passing it in Devtest Lab ARM template to access azure DevOps Repos for enabling artifact repository , but I am bit curious to know that is the PAT will be associated with azure user Id and will there be any effect to PAT when personal user Id will be deleted ? If Yes, then what is the Possible way to manage that? Any suggestion will be helpful . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you mark below response as an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

*A personal access token (PAT) is used as an alternate password to authenticate into Azure DevOps.* As long as you are able to login to ADO, you should be good. **But, note that you will not receive any emails.**

*Check out [Create a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).*